# Can I keep using my computer during 20.04 upgrade install?

Tags: upgrade

I got a notice just now as part of my regular upgrade that it can also install 20.04. So I said ok, BUT...

Then I got the notice that this could take several hours. It does not say so but the implication is I won't be able to use my computer during that time. So my question is just to make that explicit, because if so, then clearly this install will have to wait until tonight.

Second, just a gripe / rant that I also got this report about literally hundreds of packages that are going to be removed - but there is no way to save the list for later review, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: I would not use your device while it is updating. You don't need to sit by the computer while it updates- maybe you can start it before you go to sleep.  As far as your gripe/rant: you can use copy/paste, or you can review your apt logs.  You can even take a screenshot.

Comment: It can take several hours if on a dial up connection.  Most upgrades only take maybe 30 minutes and do think it ask you to close all programs.  Why cause more problems to system.  Most removed programs are updated to new versions, should disable/remove all PPAs first.

Comment: I'll say it here also... **No**, you should NOT use your computer while it installs updates or upgrades.

Comment: @Nmath  Most of my upgrades to new versions(major) usually did ask questions during upgrade, which would stop upgrade till answer.  Don't have to sit by it the whole time, but checking up on it every so often can prevent you waking up in morning to see upgrade only half way done because it is waiting for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can work on your machine, when it is going to upgrade. but as @heynnema it is not a good idea.
second answer, if you want to see all installed package list, you can see that with the following command.
open you terminal and run this.

`apt list --installed`

this will show all the installed package list of your machine.

Thank You

Comment: **No**, you **shouldn't** use your computer while it's upgrading, or installing updates... EVER!

Comment: I agree 100%. It can cause all kind of problems.

Comment: @heynnema  I agree with version upgrades, but what about the daily or weekly updates that only take a minute or two?

Comment: @crip659 Don't use the computer then either. And, in fact, if I see, say, a Firefox update, I'll quit Firefox before I proceed with the update.

Comment: @heynnema  guess I have doing it backwards all these years, sometimes don't restart browser/s for a couple of days after.

Comment: @crip659 but now you're wiser :-)

Comment: Too bad Ubuntu updates are so fast compared to Windows.  Takes longer to close everything than do the update.

Comment: Update went smoothly overnight, and then only a few hours in, I got my first crash! But we are up and at it again, now. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can work on your computer, but be aware that some software tools will change between (not within) program executions.

Will these changes affect you negatively? Maybe Yes, Maybe No. YMMV.

Will you try to execute a partially installed/updated  tool?

As part of the release upgrade, the installer will replace the Linux kernel by rebooting the system. Installers usually prompt the user before rebooting. Ensure that all of your work is saved before responding to the prompt.

Comment: Oh boy. Example... if you're using /usr/bin/firefox... and the update wants to install a newer firefox... how can it successfully do it if /usr/bin/firefox is an open file?

Comment: Through the magic of inodes. The `/usr/bin/firefox` file you're executing won't change, but the next time a user asks for `/usr/bin/firefox`, she'll get the new one. BUT `firefox` is a house of cards, opening extensions at will. Will they be the new or old versions? Will that hurt?

Comment: Exactly. If you've read the other threads, I obviously have an opinion :-)

Comment: @waltinator... yeah that goes back to my gripe (that i am going to ask a new question about), it will not "hurt". It will just prevent new instances of the new version from being launched while the old version is still up. The executable has launched its instance and it is in memory. You can delete /usr/bin/firefox and your running instances should still function. The discussion I was having before: Firefox updates in the background. I don't like it. It disables new tab launching... but I would think that this is the design that ensures no real damage occurs. just an annoying forced restart

Comment: or...that forced restart could be the warning to not use it.

Answer (score -1):

While I agree, it may not be the "best" idea to be using your computer, I think it is a bit overkill to believe the answer is simply "NO" it should not be used. I highly doubt that everyone checks to see if unattended-upgrades are running and then stops using their PC if they are.... which (i believe) happen to run everyday by default. And if there is an "in-the-know-best-practice" configuration that deviates from the default, I doubt everyone is using that. In layman's speak, most of us (unwittingly) use ubuntu while upgrades are happening.

A version upgrade - I'd be cautious and not touch it...

Any other daily or weekly updates/upgrades - I've always used it concurrently and never gave it a second thought... whether that has caused some mysterious problem... yet to be determined, and probably won't ever.

Comment: re: daily/weekly updates... and that's why you see so many questions here on AU about dpkg errors, and can't update, or update fails this way, etc.

Comment: @heynnema I'm not so obtuse to say that is not a very good possibility... But I say, show me the facts that prove that. If I see a warning that say, "hey while this is upgrading you need to stop use" then I can get behind that. But when that is not the case, I have to believe that the software was built to handle that situation. I need something other than speculation to just say "NO". and like I mentioned a lot of times you don't even have a choice. You mentioned firefox, firefox upgrades without you knowing it... I have to believe the Devs planned for the situation, at this point.

Comment: You're right... there's no warning message... but there's also no warning message when you're told "look both ways before crossing the street". If you don't look... then possibly a splat. As I mentioned earlier... there's plenty of evidence here on AU... and if you read as many questions here as I do... you'd probably start to see some patterns emerging. And the Ubuntu version of Firefox never updates itself... the Mozilla version might.

Comment: @heynnema again, I agree... but my mom told me to look both ways. Why didn't ubuntu tell me to look both ways??? Because at this point, they have built a bridge over the traffic and it is supposedly safe to use... UNTIL PROVEN OTHERWISE... and again, I'm not saying you are not correct, but the "evidence" you speak of, in court would be called, "circumstantial evidence", not direct proof. In the firefox case, are you saying the fifefox that came preinstalled with this Ubuntu could be the mozilla version? because I am "now" sitting on a browser that can't open tabs because it has updated  itself

Comment: Do updates/upgrades according to your own work flow, experience, and safety desires. Hopefully I don't see a question from you tomorrow about how some update failed :-) The Ubuntu version of Firefox, as I understand it, is slightly different than what you can download at Mozilla. And I've never seen the Ubuntu version update itself, outside of normal Software Updates. Be happy.

Comment: Regarding Firefox broken tabs... it's probably a broken profile (or bad extension). Start Firefox in safe mode, and/or choose a different profile, to test and see if that's the case.

Comment: @heynnema Unless youre going to open up a pretty deep investigation/experiment into effects of upgrading, this probably wont be productive... BUT I am interested in the firefox vs Mozilla thing. But I may have to open up another question. Because I AM !!!PISSED!!! when i have to close my browser after these background updates have happened. I am using the firefox that was preinstalled, never downloaded mozilla. No, this is an after update thing.. it is ANNOYING "hold on we need to fix one thing, RESTART button"... there seems to be no answers for it, until you just mentioned ubuntu vs mozilla.

Comment: You lost me. Did you try the profile/extension possible fix that I mentioned?

Comment: @heynnema  for some time Firefox that comes with Ubuntu does not like to load new tabs after an update if firefox is running and not updated to new version.  A simple restart of firefox fixes it.  Other browsers(Opera) do not seem to mind opening new tabs if running and not updated to new version.

Comment: @crip659 OMG bless you!!!! no one else involved knew what I was talking about. Though after a conversation with heynnema I was inspired to ask a different question about that and may have found the solution. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279041/disabling-firefox-background-upgrades ...which does "somewhat" support the argument for not using your PC during upgrades. I say somewhat because unattened-upgrades were found to be in play and most people are not even aware of them. So is this really "dangerous" or does FF just not allow correct function until restart. Oh and, Opera does do it too

Comment: @WU-TANG  Seems like firefox this does not like to open new tabs, until restart to new version of firefox.  Opera does not have this problem, will happy open new tabs.

Comment: @crip659 yeah that's been my gripe for years... I have experienced it with Opera though. Opera does not give you a nice(jerk) after-the-fact warning page like firefox does, but the new tabs do malfunction... I can't remember what the exact symptom is, but I remembered a restart was the thing that fixed it, and there is a new version there every time. I remember because that was the thing that made me give up the firefox gripe. Maybe it has changed, maybe people complained and Opera responded... I haven't seen it in a while, but then again, I've been closing opera after a few days of use.

Comment: @WU-TANG think my only gripe with Opera is it is hard to have it play some videos(facebook mainly) okay all the time.  Get it fixed and next update screws it up again.  My permanent fix is to use firefox for some vids.